# Barra de status com degradê de três cores no Android Studio

Tags: android, android-layout

Galera como fazer uma barra de status com um degradê de 3 cores (como na imagem).[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nunca tentei mas acredito que você deve criar um gradiente em xml e aplica-lo como background na sua status bar, segue um modelo de gradiente com apenas duas cores:

```
    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="@android:color/holo_blue_light"></solid>
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item>
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="@android:color/white"></solid>
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

Então aplica esse xml como backgroud da sua statusbar

Answer (score 2):

para as versões a partir da API 21 você poderia definir a cor da status bar da seguinte maneira:
Configure o tema do seu app:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@drawable/statusbar_degrade</item>
</style>
```

E o arquivo Drawable que gerará o conjunto de cores para o seu gradient:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <gradient android:centerColor="#3046d7"
            android:startColor="#58d445"
            android:endColor="#1b8f0b" />
    </shape>
</item>
</selector>
```

Depois você pode definir as cores e o formato do gradiente dentro do arquivo statusbar_degrade que você criou na pasta @drawable.

Comment: Consegui fazer essa parte, mas não to conseguindo aplicar nas activitys! @EduardoRafael